# Qt: How to find why QTextEdit is being closed?

Tags: qt, qt4

I write a simple MDI text editor using Qt 4. When a text window (`MyDoc` derived from `QTextEdit`) is being closed, I want to know whether it is being closed by pressing [X] on that child window or by closing the whole application. Then I will use this info some way (say, I want to issue a message box with an additional question in case of using [X]). How can I achieve this? I don't know a way of distinguishing that in redefined `closeEvent()`, which could be the best solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install an event filter on the global instance of QApplication and watch for Close event. It should arrive before the closeEvent() is called on your widget.